# How to build custom array in multi level foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Here is the raw data

```
Array
(
    [name] => me
    [tickets] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [equipment] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => DVR
                                    [received] => 10
                                )
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => DCT
                                    [received] => 3
                                )
                        )
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [equipment] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => DVR
                                    [received] => 4
                                )
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => DCT
                                    [received] => 6
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Users have multiple tickets, but each ticket has the same item with different 'received' amounts. I would like to `sum` the received amount into one variable/array.

Here is a demo of how I would like to get it to work like

```
Array
(
    [name] => me
    [equipment] => Array
        (
            [DVR] => 14
            [DCT] => 9
        )
)
```

Here is my most recent failed attempt at building my own array from a multidimensional array.

```
foreach($data as $user){
    $sum = [];
    $sum['name'] = $user->name;
    $sum['equipment'] = [];
    foreach($user->tickets as $ticket){
        foreach($ticket->equipments as $eqpt){
            $sum['equipment'][$eqpt['name']] += $eqpt['pivot']['received'];
        }
    }
    print_r($sum);
}
```

Comment: Could you make your example more succinct?

Comment: @tsnorri - I have cleaned up my code to make it more readable. I want to get the sum of all the equipments across all the tickets in the collection for that user into a new, clean array.

Comment: This is a very basic version of the actual environment, there are multiple users, multiple tickets for each user, multiple equipments for each ticket

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. There's only a single user in your `$data`, though, so you need to do `$data = [$data];` first.

```
foreach ($data as $user) {
    $sum = [];
    $sum['name'] = $user['name'];
    $sum['equipment'] = [];
    foreach($user['tickets'] as $ticket){
        foreach($ticket['equipment'] as $eqpt){
            $sum['equipment'][$eqpt['name']] += $eqpt['received'];
        }
    }
    print_r($sum);
}
```

- PHP arrays are accessed with [square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)
- There's probably a typo in `$ticket->equipments`.

Comment: that pivot was left in there by mistake, it is an actual level in array for the environment. The error I am getting is `Undefined index: DVR`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$array = $data; //$data is your array

$sum = array('name' => $array['name'], 'equipment' => array());

foreach($array['tickets'] as $row) {
  for($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++) {
      foreach($row['equipment'] as $infos) {
        $sum['equipment'][$infos['name']] += $infos['received'];
        //print_r($infos);
    }     
  }       
}   

print_r($sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, after much googling and trial and error this appears to work

```
$sum = [];
// $data is a collection returned by Laravel
// I am converting it to an array
foreach($data->toArray() as $user){
    $items = [];
    foreach($user['tickets'] as $ticket){
        foreach($ticket['equipments'] as $eqpt){
            $name = $eqpt['name'];

            if (! isset($items[$name]))
            {
                $items[$name] = $eqpt['received'];
            } else {
                $items[$name] += $eqpt['received'];
            }
        }
    }
    $sum[] = [
        'name' => $user['name'],
        'equipment' => $items
    ];
}
```

@tsnorri @Adrian Cid Almaguer

Comment: do you try with my answer?